# Google app script only updates document's changes after finishing running. Can I force it to refresh before?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I want to replace a piece of text inside a google document and then convert it to PDF

Here's the problem, the document is only updated with the changes AFTER the script ends. Because of this when I run the following code, the PDF doesn't have the changes done yet.

Is there a way to force it to update while the script is running?

```
var doc_open = DocumentApp.openById(fileid);
var doc_body = doc_open.getBody();

//replace text
doc_body.replaceText('{name}', student.name);
doc_body.replaceText('{email}', student.email);

//create pdf
var docblob = doc_open.getAs('application/pdf');
docblob.setName(filename + ".pdf");
var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid).createFile(docblob)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveAndClose()) method. You'll have to add another line of code to reopen the doc to do anymore operations (if needed).

Comment: Just want to say to you that I Love You.

Comment: Well that escalated quickly! ;) haha... I had the same issue with a spreadsheet that I was creating and sending as a pdf programmatically in one script. Comes to find out the keyword to search for in this scenario is 'flush'.

Comment: For anyone landing here and using "Sheets", use [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)