# Get ID from an after edited copy of a Google Doc with Google APP Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have created a script that is triggered after button click on android app.

The script I've written gets a Google Docs Template and creates a copy of it to edit it afterwards.
After being edited i want to send an email to the email that will be inserted in the app.

The email should include the body, the subject and the file attached as pdf.
I've achieved to send the email with the pdf in it but it sends the copy of the Template without being edited.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Here's my code:

```
//Make a copy of the template file
var templateID = DriveApp.getFileById('My Template ID').makeCopy().getId();

//Rename The copied file
DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).setName(codigOperari + " - " + numero + " - " + operari + " - " + cliente + " - " + data);

//Get the document body as a variable    
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(templateID);
var body = doc.getBody();

//Edit the copy of the template
body.replaceText('<<C>>',  codigOperari);
body.replaceText('<<NUMPARTE>>',  numero);
body.replaceText('<<FECHA>>', data);
body.replaceText('<<CLIENTE>>', cliente);
body.replaceText('<<CORREO>>', e.parameter.ETEmail);
body.replaceText('<<ORDENTRABAJO>>', e.parameter.ETMotiu);
body.replaceText('<<OPERARIO>>', operari);

//A lot of data more

//Message to be sent
var message = {
    to: e.parameter.ETEmail,
    subject: "Subject",
    body: "This is a Test",
    name: "Name",
    attachments: [DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs(MimeType.PDF)
.setName(codigOperari + " - " + numero + " - " + operari + " - " + cliente + " - " + data)]
  }
//Send Email
MailApp.sendEmail(message);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding them as an editor instead of sending them an email? It's tacky and not as professional as the email but if you share the doc with them rather than attach it, that might solve the problem. Use the .addEditor('email') method on the DocumentApp object (var doc in this example)

Comment: Also, why is the attachment being sent the ActiveDocument? Isn't the attachment you're trying to send the doc variable? DocumentApp.openById() does not make the document "active". If you thought that you made the document active after "opening" it, that is where you went wrong. DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() will only ever give you the document from which the script comes from (if this script is free-standing, you'll get an error). The only way you can access the newly created file is with the .openById('id') method (which you are already using).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you a comment as well, but I believe your issue is that you're sending the `ActiveDocument` and not the document that was edited.

`DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` will only ever return the document the script is "anchored" to. If you open up a Google Doc or Spreadsheet, go to the Tools menu, and click Script Editor, you will be given an Apps Script file that is **bound** to your Google Doc. You can access the document directly in this Apps Script ONLY with `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()`. Trying to edit this Google Doc from anywhere else will require the `DocumentApp.openById()` method.

My guess is that once you ran `var body = DocumentApp.openById(templateID)` you thought that you actually opened the document and activated it, which lead you to think that all you had to do was attach the "active document". This is wrong though, as you will only ever be attaching the source document. I'm assuming this is the template.

You already have the solution though. The document you're trying to send is stored in the `doc` variable. `var doc = DocumentApp.openById()` gives you a variable that points to that spreadsheet indefinitely. You can access this document through this variable at any point (you do so right afterwards with the `var body = doc.getBody()` statement.

Let me know if this fixed it!

Comment: I could send the email, but the pdf was empty. What solved the issue was this post that someone comented before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893183/google-app-script-only-updates-documents-changes-after-finishing-running-can-i

Comment: Yeah I ended up seeing that after the fact. Sorry for the wrong answer but glad you figured it out!